# Problems with the VariationalD (VariationalMethods package)

Tags: series-expansion, variational-calculus

I'm facing the following problem: The VariationalD function doens't commute with the series expasion. Physically this means that if I compute the equation of motion starting with an Hamiltonian with a small correction and then I expand it, the result will be different from the one I obtain computing the equation of motion starting with the leading order of the Hamiltonian.

lets take the function

$$f(x+af(x))$$

**1. First differentiate and then expand**

```
VariationalD[f[x + a f[x]], f[x], x] = a f'[x+af[x]]
```

or, rewritted in a friendly way
$$\frac{\delta f(x + a f(x))}{\delta f(x)} = a f'(x+a f(x))$$
then I need to expand the previous result

```
Series[a f'[x + a f[x]], {a,0,1}] = a f'[x] + O(a^2)
```

So finally I get
$$af'(x)+O(a^2)$$

**First expand and then differentiate**

Now I follow the opposite way

```
Series[f[x+a f[x]], {a,0,1}] = f[x] + a f[x]f'[x] + O(a^2)
```

Then I take the functional derivative of the previous equation

```
VariationalD[f[x] + a f[x]f'[x] + O(a^2), f[x], x] = 1 + O(a^2)
```

namely,
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta f(x)} \left( f(x) + a f(x) f'(x) + O(a^2) \right) = 1 + O(a^2)$$

Comment: Your code has numerous syntax problems. Brackets don't match and `af[x]` should be `a f[x]` (with a space) because otherwise you end up with a completely different function called `af` instead of multiplying `a` with `f[x]`.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Sorry about that, but don't worry: they are just typo in the question, not in the code I really used. I edited the text.